# How do we use Class.forName to get a primitive byte class?

Tags: java, reflection

We can use `Class.forName("[B")` to get a byte array but what do we put in for a primitive byte class:

For example

```
  Class.forName("??") => java.lang.Byte.TYPE
```

I tried `"java.lang.Byte.TYPE"`, `"byte"` and `"B"` but they don't work

Comment: Primitives aren't classes in Java. There's no way to do this. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do the inverse. Do byte.class and invoke getName on the result.

Comment: @jkin But they do have corresponding Class objects.

Comment: Can't be done. Per the suggestion by @SotiriosDelimanolis `Class.forName(byte.class.getName());` throws an exception.

Comment: I'm afraid, what you are looking for is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, `Class` instances are created by a `ClassLoader`. So you could have 2 `Class` instances for the same class from different `ClassLoader` instances.

This is not true for primitive types. There is only one `Class` instance for each primitive type per JVM. It is created and returned from a `native` method in the `Class` class.

```
static native Class getPrimitiveClass(String name);
```

This is assigned directly to `Byte.TYPE`

```
public static final Class<Byte> TYPE = (Class<Byte>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("byte");
```

or returned when you do

```
byte.class
```

You can't use `Class.forName(..)` to get it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. [The doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) does seem to suggest this might be the case, saying:

> Returns the **Class object** associated with the **class or interface** with the given string name.

Since primitives do not have a class (only a *Class object* to represent them for purposes of reflection), they cannot be retrieved this way.

If there is a use for wanting this (IE not just wondering out of curiosity), the following helper class includes them:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Collections;

public final class ForName {
    private ForName() {}

    private static final Map<String, Class<?>> PRIM = (
        Collections.unmodifiableMap(
            new HashMap<String, Class<?>>(16) {
                {
                    for(Class<?> cls : new Class<?>[] {
                        void.class,
                        boolean.class,
                        char.class,
                        byte.class,
                        short.class,
                        int.class,
                        long.class,
                        float.class,
                        double.class
                    }) {
                        put(cls.getName(), cls);
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    );

    public static Class<?> forName(final String name)
    throws ClassNotFoundException {
        final Class<?> prim = PRIM.get(name);

        if(prim != null)
            return prim;

        return Class.forName(name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For primitive types and void, Class objects cannot be obtained from forName. You must use the class literals, **int.class**, or the TYPE field of the appropriate wrapper class, such **Void.TYPE**.

If you insist to use forName, you could first get the Class object for the corresponding array type, then use the getComponentType to get the primitive type itself. For example:

```java
  Class<?> c = Class.forName("[B");
  Class<?> primitive = c.getComponentType();
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

```
Class<?> t = Class.forName("java.lang.Byte");
```

I haven't tested this, plus you haven't shown any example code for what you are trying to do....

Comment: OP seems to be looking for the `Class` object for `byte`, not for `java.lang.Byte`.